# How to publish a multi project solution to azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, visual-studio-2013, publish, publishing

I have a solution with a few projects my main project MVC a seperate project that holds all my object classes and a third that has by db classes and enity framweork stuff. When i publish the project to azure only the MVC project seems to be going up.
Im using MVC,WebApi2, EF 5, and VS2013

this is what it looks like.

[image]

So I looked at this a bit closer I think it is publishing the required DLL but in my main project im using api controllers to handle data and normal controllers to handle the views. This works fine on my machine but when published to azure it is getting "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" could it be an issue with the apicontrollers and azure not playing nice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a reference issue where NuGet did not install entity framework correctly, and the default route was not going to the right place. To fix i ran the install command for Entity Framework again and re published.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide some more information about the other projects in your solution?

If they are just classes you are referencing, upon building the project your main solution should put a compiled .dll to reference in your MVC folder. This will get published up to Azure.

Also, how are you publishing to Azure? Are you using the built in Azure Publish tools in VS2013?

Comment: Yes there just classes, Yes using the default publish tools in vs 2013. So I looked at this a bit closer I think it is publishing the required DLL but in my main project im using api controllers to handle data and normal controllers to handle the views. This works fine on my machine but when published to azure it is getting "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" could it be an issue with the apicontrollers and azure not playing nice?